# Converter potência

Tags: javascript, html, operadores

Eu tenho uma função `format(input)` que transforma a citação de código de uma expressão numérica, para ficar de uma forma mais legível para o usuário com caracteres unicode.

e.g. `"3 * 2 + 1 - 5 / 2pi" -> "3 × 2 + 1 - 5 ÷ 2π"`

Porém, com a potenciação, eu quero fazer o número que está sendo elevado ficar sobrescrito (`¹²³`), para isso usei:

```
output = input.replace(/\s*\^\s*(\S+)/g, '<sup>$1</sup>');
```

`REGEX: zero ou mais espaços, um ^, zero ou mais espaços, ( um ou mais não-espaços )`

O que funciona bem para a maioria dos casos em que um número está sendo elevado a outro (e.g. `x ^ 2 -> x²`). Mas se o numero for elevado a uma expressão (e.g. `x ^ (2 - 6)`) acaba tendo um erro (por causa dos espaços)...

Então... como eu faço para transformar as potências depois do `^` em sobrescrito, nessa ocasião?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esta REGEX resolverá seu problema:

```
\s*\^\s*(\(.*.\)|\S+)
```

1. O **\(.*.\)** fará o *match* de parênteses, e agrupará o seu conteúdo.
2. O *OR* seguido do **\S+** procurará os caracteres que não forem espaços em branco.

**Inputs / Outputs**

```
x ^ 2 -> x²              //x<sup>2</sup> -> x²
x ^ (2 - 6)              //x<sup>(2 - 6)</sup>
x ^ (2 - [6 + {x + y }]) //x<sup>(2 - [6 + {x + y }])</sup>
x ^ y                    //x<sup>y</sup>
3x ^ 7y                  //3x<sup>7y</sup>
z ^ y2                   //z<sup>y2</sup>
9 ^ √4                   //9<sup>√4</sup>
9 ^ 30                   //9<sup>30</sup>
2^1000000                //2<sup>1000000</sup>
x ^ (2 - 1) + 3 - 5      //x<sup>(2 - 1)</sup> + 3 - 5
```

Segue link dos testes realizados: https://regex101.com/r/i7ORyt/3

Comment: está funcionando só com essa parte do codigo, mas quando adiciona novos elementos (e.g. `x ^ (2 - 1) + 3 - 5`) a resposta é matematicalmente errada: `x<sup>(2 - 1) + 3 - 5</sup>` onde o certo seria `x<sup>2 - 1</sup> + 3 - 5`...

Comment: Corrigi a resposta com uma nova REGEX, contemplando o caso de teste não coberto pela solução anterior.

Comment: A regex funcionou perfeitamente para a questão, como em `x ^ 2 + 1` -> `x<sup>2+1</sup>` porém se não tivesse espaços: `x^2+1` isso iria falhar. eu consegui resolver pelo que me parece usando a seguinte regex, trocando o `\S+` (não espaço) por `\w|\d` (letra ou dígito) : "`\s*\^\s*(\(.*.\)|\w+|\d+)`" :: (https://regex101.com/r/i7ORyt/3) tirando por regex recursiva, mas acho que isso não tem como.

Answer (score 0):

Elimine todos os espaços dentro de parênteses na string antes de aplicar o `<sup>`:

```
input = "2 ^ (2 - 6) + 5 ^ (2 + 3) - 6 ^ 10";
input = input.replace(/\s+(?=[^(\]]*\))/g, "");
output = input.replace(/\s*\^\s*(\S+)/g, '<sup>$1</sup>');
```

```js
input = "2 ^ (2 - 6) + 5 ^ (2 + 3) - 6 ^ 10";
input = input.replace(/\s+(?=[^(\]]*\))/g, "");
output = input.replace(/\s*\^\s*(\S+)/g, '<sup>$1</sup>');
$("#teste").html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste"></div>
```

Comment: funciona corretamente para esse exemplo: `2 ^ (2 - 6)`. mas em uma outra expressão (e.g. `2 ^ (2 - 6) + 5 / 2` ele retorna `2 ^ <sup>(2 - 6)
 + 5 / 2</sup>` onde o matematicamente correto seria `2 ^ <sup>2 - 6</sup> + 5 / 2` (a potência só tem como expoente o termo entre parênteses)

Comment: @HenryPKDevelopingApps Veja agora.